# Ubuntu 14.04 - Won't turn swap on at boot

Tags: partitioning, swap

I'm using ubuntu as a hypervisor with my production OSes running in VMware.

Since I installed everything onto an SSD, I placed the swap file off on a data HDD during install. Once I got everything setup, I needed to move the swapfile to a different section of a different physical HDD.

Being honest, I know enough about linux to get it to boot. I'm a windows power user who is completely flummexed trying to get this to work. I had no problems getting my virtual XP & 8 machines to use pagefiles I setup on HDDs even though their virtual machine files are stored on the SSD.

How do I get the swap space to turn on at boot. I have 14gb's of RAM, but VMware wants a swap file anyways. With terabytes of HDD space, I have no problem allocating a partition for this use, and without any other ideas, I used teh standard windows practice of as much swap space as you have ram.

Sorry for the long winded question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the following line to your `/etc/fstab` to activate the swap partition at boot.

```
/dev/sdx  none    swap    sw     0       0
```

Comment: Two things, the partition I created, and turn on manually every time I want to run VMware is at /dev/sdc2. That would replace sdx in your above line?

And how do I edit that file? I'm afraid I only know how to edit files in Windows, sorry.

Comment: Yes `/dev/sdc2` replaces `/dev/sdx`. From commandline use `nano /etc/fstab` to edit the file.

Answer (score 0):

You can use swapfile or swap partition - your choice.
If not much use  - I think swapfile will be enough.

Anyway - you have to create one of whatever size you need.
Say - 1GB, just for example:

1. create the empty file of 1GB size:

dd if=/dev/zero of=/swapfile bs=1024 count=1048576

2. The best change permissions to allow only root to use it:

chown root:root /swapfile
chmdo 600 /swapfile

3. make it swap
   mkswap /swapfile
4. also add it to /etc/fstab if you want it mounted automatically:
   /swapfile none swap defaults 0 0
5. enable swap on that file
   swapon /swapfile

Of course you can locate it somewhere else, not necessarily in the root filesystem, and reflect it in the commands above.